# Post dynamically created HTML page to form action

Tags: c#, .net

I have a piece of code which generates HTML string. In the HTML I have a `form` element which I want to submit programmatically. I am trying to do it with `WebClient` but I can't seem to make it work. This is an automation of a legacy functionality and all this is done on call of a WebApi so I don't have any other option.

**My HTML Sample**

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>File Uploader</TITLE>
<META content="IE = edge" http-equiv="X - UA - Compatible">

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV align=center>
<H1>File Uploader </ h1></ div>
<FORM id="wmMainForm" method="post" name="wmForm" action="https://www.example.com/post.php" target="_blank">
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<H3>File ID</H3></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=9636963 name=file_id></TD>
<TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<H3>File summaries </H3></TD>
<TD><INPUT value='O:21:"co_bl_e...s:8:"9636963";}' name=entFileSummary0></TD>
<TD><INPUT value='O:21:"qo_bl_e...s:8:"9636963";}' name=entFileSummary1></TD>
<TD><INPUT value='O:20:"co_re_en...s:8:"9636963";}' name=entFileSummary2></TD>
<TD><INPUT name=entFileSummary3></TD>
<TD><INPUT value='O:19:"rp_et...s:8:"9636963";}' name=etFileSummary4></TD>
<TD><INPUT value='O:21:"st_bl_e...s:8:"9636963";}' name=etFileSummary5></TD>
<TD><INPUT name=etFileSummary6></TD>
<TD><INPUT value='O:20:"ac_re_en...s:8:"9636963";}' name=etFileSummary7></TD>
<TD><INPUT name=etFileSummary8></TD>
<TD><INPUT value='O:19:"mp_re_et...s:8:"9636963";}' name=etFileSummary9></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<H3>File Size in bytes </H3></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=15923 name=etFileSize0></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=472 name=etFileSize1></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=14789 name=etFileSize2></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=0 name=etFileSize3></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=1000 name=etFileSize4></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=2524 name=etFileSize5></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=0 name=etFileSize6></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=14830 name=etFileSize7></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=0 name=etFileSize8></TD>
<TD><INPUT value=1110 name=etFileSize9></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>

<DIV align=right><INPUT type=submit value=upload></DIV></FORM></H1></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

**My Posting Code**

```
   using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(Constants.URL, htmlPostContentLoaded);
        }
```

**Note: Constants.URL and form's action both have same URL and htmlPostContentLoaded has the HTML content.**

Answer (score 0):

you should trace the button action url with network section in developer console of your browser and send a request to that url for pressing the button
[maybe this link can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421487/c-sharp-click-html-button-from-webclient)